# Set Builder Notation: "lift" the predicate

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

My question is on "lifting" the predicate out of the predicate part of Set Builder Notation.

For Example:

$$
S = \{ \; x \; | \; x \in \mathbb{N} \;\text{ and }\; 0 \lt x \leq 10 \; \}
$$

Can I write that as:

$$
\Phi(x) = 0 \lt x \leq 10 \\
S = \{ \; x \; | \; x \in \mathbb{N} \;\text{ and }\; \Phi(x) \;  \}
$$

I am asking this because I want to understand SBN (I'm not a mathematician) and predicates in general. This question could also have been: "How can I bind a predicate to a name?"

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is if I can write $\Phi(x) = 0 \lt x \leq 10$ and later use $\Phi(x)$ in a set builder.

Comment: In f-o logic, you have to separate the many uses of the symbol $=$; in the formal language, it is a binary predicate : $x=y$ where $x,y$ are *terms*. You can use it also in the meta-theory, like your example: in this case, you are "defining" an *abbreviation* $\Phi(x)$ for the formula $0 \le x \le 10$. In this case you can use $:=$ or other symbols to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: SBN can be very useful in informal proofs. To resolve this kind of question, however, it may be instructive to use more formal FOL statements instead, e.g. defining  $S$ here such that $\forall x:[x\in S \iff x\in\mathbb{N}\land 0\lt x\leq 10]$.

Comment: Using SBN, you could also write $S=\{x\in \mathbb{N} | 0\lt x \leq 10\}$ and $S=\{x\in \mathbb{N} | \Phi(x)\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Formal_set_builder_notation_sets) is exactly an "operation" that transform a *predicate* into a *term* (i.e. a name).

We start with the predicate $\varphi(x)$ (e.g. "$x$ is Even") and applying to it the SBN we get the "name" of the set: $E = \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$ of all and only those objects that satisfy the predicate (i.e. the set of *even* numbers).

---

In the formal syntax, $\varphi$ can be any (well-formed) formula with one free variable.

Thus, if we abbreviate with $\varphi(x)$ the formula:

> $\exists z \ (x = 2 \times z) \land x \le 10$

the set $E_{10} = \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$ will contain all and only the *even* numbers up to $10$.

---

See e.g. :

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA2) (2nd ed - 2001), **Ch.ZERO Useful Facts about Sets**, page 2:

> We write “$\{ x \mid \text{__} x \text{__} \}$” for the set of all objects $x$ such that $\text{__} x \text{__}$.
>
> We will take considerable liberty with this notation. For example, $\{m, n
>  \mid m < n \in \mathbb N \}$ is the set of all ordered pairs of natural numbers for which the first component is smaller than the second. And $\{x \in A \mid \text{__} x \text{__} \}$ is the set of all elements $x$ in $A$ such that $\text{__} x \text{__}$.

Comment: And it doesn't matter where this predicate $\phi(x)$ is defined? In other words: do I need to one-line my "operation" or can I scaffold it slowly from multiple little parts? (Also, can I use an equals sign to define a predicate? It feels a bit weird)

Comment: Using an equals sign is a little weird, yes. Informally, people sometimes use ":=", but better might be $\stackrel{def}\iff$. That's \stackrel{def}\iff inside dollar signs.

Comment: Thank you all for the great help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The hardest part is learning to write it down in a correct way. The concepts are relatively easy to learn but the terms and notation are frighteningly difficult :)

Comment: @CarlosKelkboom - you can try with some introductory material : Stephen Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) (2013) and Stephen Simpson, [Foundations of Mathematics](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/fom.pdf) (2009).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Here's a rough approximation to how most mathematicians would write it.

Let $\Phi$ denote the unary predicate on $\mathbb{R}$ defined as follows.

$$\Phi(x) \iff 0 < x \leq 10$$

Let $S$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ defined as follows.

$$ S = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \Phi(n)\}$$

I'd probably write that last one a bit more like so:

Let $S$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ defined as follows.

$$n \in S \iff \Phi(n)$$

Comment: Thank you for the example. Your "code" makes a lot of sense and makes it easy to follow. Your last example took me a bit longer to understand because I didn't see $\mathbb{N}$ return in the formula but now that I understand it I appreciate it.

Comment: @CarlosKelkboom, its worth pointing that the reason you don't see $\mathbb{N}$ in that formula is because I've suppressed the universal quantifiers. Really, it should read: $$\left(\mathop{\forall}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\right) \; n \in S \iff \Phi(n)$$

Comment: @CarlosKelkboom, other other thing worth noting is that $n \in S$ basically means the same thing as $S(n),$ except that the latter is "predicate notation" while the former is "subset notation."

Answer (score 1):

A minor point: You should probably define the unary predicate $\Phi$ such that $\forall x\in \mathbb{N}:[\Phi(x)\iff 0 \lt x \leq 10]$. Otherwise OK.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example! I have three questions, can I read this as: "For every $x$ in $\mathbb{N}$, $\Phi(x)$ is true if and only if $x$ is between 0 and 11"? My second question is: why isn't it "$\exists x$ in $\mathbb{N}$"? I get the $\forall$ when defining a set S but I don't understand it in this "phrasing". My last question is about the brackets, do they have a special meaning? Or are they just a way to group terms?

Comment: A1: Yes. A2: $\exists x \in \mathbb{N}\cdots$ means that what follows is presumed to be true for at least one natural number, not necessarily every one of them. A3: The brackets are use to group items and to indicate the scope of the quantifiers.

Comment: Thank you for answering my novice questions.