# Are sets just predicates with syntactic sugar?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Do mathematicians agree/accept that "sets are just predicates with syntactic sugar"?

If not, then Why not? I mean, I can translate between $ x \in S $ and $ S(x) $. Will that change the correctness of a proof?

Is there some nuance in university-level math that makes the distinction necessary?

Comment: How does this differ from your other question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801231/why-do-we-use-both-sets-and-predicates ?

Comment: No; see [Russell's Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/). *Predicates* are syntactical objects in the language of logic: set is a "mathematical object" of set theory. The assumption that for every "imaginable" *concept* we can assume the "mathematical" existence of the corresponding *class* (or *collection*) leads to contradictions.

Comment: @ Barry Cipra : In that question I kind of assumed that the answer to this one is yes. But I realized since then, that this might not be the case.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA So can I say that sets are "contradiction-free predicates"?

Comment: @foobar: unfortunately, there are several approaches to avoiding the contradictions. ZF tries to avoid them by restricting to predicates on elements of a given set. Systems like Quine's NF try to avoid them by restricting the syntactic form of the predicates used to define a set.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I disagree. *Predicate symbols* are syntactical objects. *Predicates* are functions $X \rightarrow \{\mathrm{true},\mathrm{false}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Set theory *is* a form of logic, and logic *is* a form of set theory. In my opinion this is made most clear in the form of category theory.

However, I would not expect the "typical" mathematician to be sufficiently fluent in formal logic to deal with this comfortably.

In my opinion, the typical mathematician works in first-order logic on top of (some fragment of) ZFC. Having two "universes" like that is a subtle and confusing thing — maintaining a sharp distinction between "predicate" and "set" is how the typical mathematician keeps them straight.

Comment: The last paragraph is the crux of this answer; in the context of ZFC, people use the distinction between set and predicate to help maintain a distinction between two different universes.

Comment: Most mathematicians use infinite order logic. The restriction to first order is a very unnatural one, only justified when actally doingn logic, mostly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which axioms you are using. In ZF, the predicate $S(x) = \text{True}, \forall x$ does not correspond to a set.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the Universe set of whatever application we discuss? I mean the complement of the empty set.

Comment: since S(x)=False is the empty set

Comment: @foobar In the usual foundations for mathematics (ZFC and related systems), the universe is not a set, i.e. there is no set of all sets.

Comment: @  Alex Kruckman But in highschool math, and even in probability theory, we use the universe and complement. So are those incorrect?

Comment: Of course high school math is not as ambitious as University math ! The universes used in high school are usually for example the set of days of the week. They are not supposed to be universal in the sense discussed here.

Comment: @Simon In lecture 1 of MIT's probability class the prof uses bothuniverse and complement for a proof of a basic theorem directly from the axioms http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/video-lectures/lecture-1-probability-models-and-axioms/

Comment: @Eli: you should learn about [set theories with a universal set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set) before you pontificate on this topic.

Comment: @RobArthan: Apologies! I think what I should say is that, in the "usual" setup (at least ZFC), this predicate does not correspond to a set. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your framework, but in *structuralist mathematics*, sets and predicates are very different. Here's the low-down:

**Idea 0.** Sets form a category. Its called $\mathbf{Set}$.

**Idea 1.** Given an object $X$ of the category $\mathbf{Set}$, we define a new category $\mathrm{Sub}(X)$ as follows:

- an *object* $\mathfrak{a}$ consists of a set $\overline{\mathfrak{a}}$ equipped with an injection $\eta_\mathfrak{a} : \overline{\mathfrak{a}} \rightarrow X$.
- a *morphism* $g:\mathfrak{a} \rightarrow \mathfrak{b}$ consists of a function $\overline{g} : \overline{\mathfrak{a}} \rightarrow \overline{\mathfrak{b}}$ such that $\eta_{\mathfrak{b}} \circ 
  \overline{g} = \eta_{\mathfrak{a}}$.

Its easy to show that $\mathrm{Sub}(X)$ is a [thin category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thin+category). This means we can treat it as a partially-ordered set; $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{b}$ means there exists a morphism $\mathfrak{a} \rightarrow \mathfrak{b}$, and $\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{b}$ means there exists an isomorphism $\mathfrak{a} \rightarrow \mathfrak{b}$, or equivalently, that there is a morphism going each way.

**Idea 2.** The poset of truthvalues can be defined as $\mathrm{Sub}(1)$, where $1$ is the set with $1$ element.

**Idea 3.** Given an object $X$ of the category $\mathbf{Set}$, we define a new category $\mathrm{Pred}(X)$ as follows:

- an *object* $P$ is just a function $P : X \rightarrow \mathrm{Sub}(1)$.
- a *morphism* $g:P \rightarrow Q$ is just a guarantee that for all $x \in X$, we have $P(x) \subseteq Q(x)$.

As before, $\mathrm{Pred}(X)$ also happens to be a thin category, for all sets $X$.

**Idea 4.** We can view both $\mathrm{Sub}$ and $\mathrm{Pred}$ as functors $\mathbf{Set}^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Pos}$.

- $\mathrm{Sub}(f)$ is given by taking pullbacks: $$\mathrm{Sub}(f)(\mathfrak{b}) = f^{-1}(\mathfrak{b})$$
- $\mathrm{Pred}(f)$ is given by precomposition: $$\mathrm{Pred}(f)(P) = f \circ P$$

**Idea 5.** These functors turn out to be naturally isomorphic, thereby legitimizing the whole "subsets and predicates are the same thing" viewpoint.

---

So in this language, your question becomes:

> Are *subsets* just predicates with syntactic sugar?

Yes, they're pretty much the same thing; once you've got a few definitions and observations under your belt, at least. You can indeed switch between them in that way.